# error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand

Tags: c++, operators, winsock2

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error yet the same class worked perfectly under VS15 now I'm using VS12, it's a simple Winsock2 implementation,

```
int Net::createServer(int port, int protocol) 
{
    int status;

    // ----- Initialize network stuff -----
    status = initialize(port, protocol);
    if (status != NET_OK)
        return status;

    localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    // listen on all addresses

    // bind socket
    if (bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        status = WSAGetLastError();          // get detailed error
        return ((status << 16) + NET_BIND_FAILED);
    }
    bound = true;
    mode = SERVER;

    return NET_OK;
}
```

the problem comes from here

```
if (bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

Console Logs :

```
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=false,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=SOCKET &,
1>              _V0_t=SOCKADDR *,
1>              _V1_t=size_t,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
1>          ]
```

Comment: Your code using _Winsock_ worked under Ubuntu? Impressive...

Comment: Yes Yes it was a mistake

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of such a large code dump. Also, your include guard is illegal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: What is the signature of `bind()`?

Comment: std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>

Comment: @BaummitAugen I can't reproduce my problem with a minimal code , my question have allready a minimal exemple and I've provided the code that reproduce to exacte same issue

Comment: @Eddy This is _not_ a minimal example. 90% of the code has nothing to do with your problem. That said, your code is calling [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), probably because of a `using namespace std` somewhere. I guess you're running into a naming collision.

Comment: @Eddy You certainly do not need dozens of namespace scoped variables, long comments and all those member variables to demonstrate such a compilation error, and you most likely do not need the full implementation for every member function either. Go show some effort.

Comment: Most likely, you are `using namespace std` (the terrible thing to do!) and now BSD sockets `bind` is conflicting with `std::bind`. Stop using standard namespace once and for all.

Comment: ok I'm sorry @BaummitAugen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(A bit of leap of faith here, but I am pretty sure I got it right).
The reason for the error is that you have a `using namespace std` statement somewhere in your program (the terrible thing to do!) and now the BSD socket `bind()` function is conflicting with the STL `std::bind` function.

Stop using `using namespace std` statements once and for all, and the problem will go away.  Otherwise, you have to qualify which namespace to pull `bind()` from, in this case the global namespace:

```
if (::bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```